# Why doesn't my filter function work? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

`if` block is executing properly. What is wrong with the code?

```js
let arr = [4, -4, 5.8, 1.6];
let newA = arr.filter((x) => {
  if (x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x)) {
    return x * x;
  }
})

console.log(newA);
```

Expected output

```
[16]
```

Actual output:

```
[4]
```

why?

Comment: `Filter` should return true/false result, what you're looking is probably `map`.

Comment: Because `filter` expects the predicate to return a boolean (`true`/`false`), and you return `x * x` which evaluates to for example `16` for your first element which is a `truthy` value i.e. is not filtered from your result set.

Answer (score 5):

The given code, does the filtering part, because any quadratic positive integer is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, but it does not return the new value.

It looks like, you need two actions, one filtering and changing the filtered values.

In this case you need [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for getting positive interger numbers and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a quadratic value.

```js
let array = [4, -4, 5.8, 1.6],
    result = array
        .filter(x => x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x))
        .map(x => x * x);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is already explained in previous answer, you can use `reduce` if you want to use single function

```js
let arr = [4, -4, 5.8, 1.6];
let newA = arr.reduce(function(accumulator, current) {
  if (current > 0 && Number.isInteger(current)) {
    accumulator.push(current * current);
  }
  return accumulator
}, [])
console.log(newA)
```

Comment: This is how I will solve the problem too... There is no need to iterate twice on the array.

Answer (score 1):

Filter just filters the value and return boolean result.. You can use `map` as below,

```js
let arr = [4, -4, 5.8, 1.6];
let newA = arr.filter((x) => x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x))
.map((x) => x * x);

console.log(newA);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `reduce` method :

```js
let arr = [4, -4, 5.8, 1.6];

let newA = arr.reduce( ( acc, x ) => {
  if ( x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x) ) { acc = acc.concat( [x*x] ) } ;
  return acc;
}, []) ;

console.log(newA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the use case, but looks like to be "get the square of all positive integers in an array". If it is then the below code should work.

```
let arr3=[4,-4,5.8,1.6];   
let new3 = arr3.filter((x)=>{ 
    return (x>0 && Number.isInteger(x));
}).map(function(y){ 
return y*y;
})
```

First extract the list of all positive integers and then return the square of each item in the list.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let arr = [4, -4, 5.8, 1.6];
let newA = arr.filter((x) => {
  if (x > 0 && Number.isInteger(x)) {
    return x * x;
  }
})

console.log(newA);
```

Comment: Just copying the code from the question is not an answer, right?